# UITableView not rendering cells inside UIContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am running into a problem displaying data inside a UITableView. I have tried implementing my needs in several different ways but all of them seem to result in the same thing. Here is my latest attempt of trying to house the content in a UIContainerView...

### Current Setup

- PeopleContainerView: Contains a UITableView, dataSource & delegates set through IB
- PeopleViewController: Contains a UIContainerView

  - UIContainerView: Linked to PeopleContainerView (above)
- SomeOtherViewController: Loads PeopleViewController from the Storyboard and inserts it using addSubview

The end goal is to load the PeopleViewController as a subview of a UIScrollView at runtime elsewhere in the project. This works fine. However, when this is done the table inside of PeopleContainerView is empty. The 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' & 'numberOfRowsInSection' methods are called and returning the proper data. However 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' appears to never be called. I have checked with breakpoints & print in various spots and the tableview is not nil and has all the proper connections made.

If I pop into the storyboard and set my PeopleContainerView to be the initial view, then the table populates as expected.

...Ideas? Thanks!

### Edit

This is how I load PeopleViewController into SomeOtherViewController

```
let vcPeople = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeopleView") as UIViewController!
let viewPeople = vcPeople.view
viewPeople.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(viewPeople)
```

I know the view is loading and sizing up fine as I can see the search bar that I added to it and blank cells but unfortunately no cells with the data I specified. Unless ran as the initial view from SB.

Comment: did you also set the datasource and delegate in the viewDidLoad (tableView.delegate = self, tableView.datasource.self)?

Comment: I set the source for tableView to its containing view, PeopleContainerView, in IB. Tried setting them in viewDidLoad as well but that had no change.

Answer (score 0):

Come onnnn really UGGGHHH. I was missing addChildViewContoller... Adjusted working example below:

```
let vcPeople = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeopleView") as! PeopleViewController!
let viewPeople = vcPeople.view
viewPeople.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.addChildViewController(vcPeople)
scrollView.addSubview(viewPeople)
```